# Add an image into an Rook web app using css

Tags: r, r-rook-package

I have the following code which should produce a simple page with an image as background

```
r <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
g <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
b <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)

col <- rgb(r, g, b)
dim(col) <- dim(r)

library(grid)
jpeg(filename="image.jpg")
grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
dev.off()

library(Rook)
server <- Rhttpd$new()

server$add(
  app=function(env){
    req <- Rook::Request$new(env)
    res <- Rook::Response$new()
    #....# r code
    res$write('
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>              
<style>

body
{
background-image: url("image.jpg");
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</h1>
</body>
</html>')

    res$finish()
  },
  name='webApp'
)

server$start(quiet=TRUE)
server$browse("webApp")
```

However, it doesn't show the image. I currently use a lot of `css` style formatting into the `<head>` tag but only `background-image` seems not to work... (just exporting everything inside the function `res$write` into a `.html` file and opening with browser does show the image)

EDIT:

NB: Relative or Absolute path does not make any difference unfortunately. Firebug and chrome dev tools both show the css line and no error is displayed. Can anyone of you see the image in the background running the example above?

Comment: Possibly an issue with the location of the image? Does adding a path to the `background-image` line help?

Comment: What's getting to the browser? Maybe you could use the Firebug extension of Firefox to track down the error? Any 404 or other error?

Comment: @JerryWho I'll answer your question tomorrow. For now I can say that using the exact html code into a normal .html page shows perfectly the Image.

Comment: @HongOoi tried both relative and absolute path

Comment: You wrote that opening the html-page locally is just fine. But with firebug you'll see what the webserver (rook) is delivering. maybe it is sending the wrong content-type for the image or doesn't find the image at all. You can also try to add this image in an img-tag. Just to test whether rook is delivering the image correctly.

Comment: Just another guess: Maybe you have to reference the image absolutely. In http://goo.gl/BdVfV I found an example where images are delivered and are referenced absolutely.

Comment: I just removed the css formatting and put the image into the `<body>` tag. No go there either. It may be that Rook simply can't handle background images.

Comment: @HongOoi that's my first guess... I really doesn't hope so. If so, probably it'd be fixed deploying the app in rApache(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an issue with paths. 
TLDR. add your working directory and give it a name (pic for example)

Try the following:

```
library(Rook)
server <- Rhttpd$new()
r <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
g <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)
b <- matrix(runif(9, 0, 1), 3)

col <- rgb(r, g, b)
dim(col) <- dim(r)

library(grid)
jpeg(filename="image.jpg")
grid.raster(col, interpolate=FALSE)
dev.off()




server$add(app = File$new(getwd()), name = 'pic')


server$add(
  app=function(env){
    req <- Rook::Request$new(env)
    res <- Rook::Response$new()
    #....# r code
    res$write('
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>              
<style>

body
{
background-image: url("pic/image.jpg");
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</h1>
</body>
</html>')

    res$finish()
  },
  name='webApp'
)

server$start(quiet=TRUE)
server$browse("webApp")
```

EDIT:
Try working with the temporary directory:

```
jpeg(filename=paste0(tempdir(), "/image.jpg"))
```

and

```
server$add(app = File$new(tempdir()), name = 'pic')
```

Comment: `R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)`

Comment: you add() two app to the server: `pic` and `webapp`. everything you do on the first doesn't affect the second. So, calling `server$browse("webapp")` you're doing nothing different than what I did. Have you misspelled anything? cause you say it's working on your side

Comment: Files need to be served. You need to define a rook application to serve your static files from your working directory. The file class does this. The code above works fine for me. I have opened a clean linux R and sourced the above in and get Hello World with multi colored background. I switch to a seperate windows 8 machine 64 bit. I open a clean seesion of R and source  the code in. I get Hello world with a multi colored background. You may have some permission issues on your working directory. Are you on a locked down machine of some sort? You can try using the temporary directory.

Comment: thanks for this explanation I'll try to understand it... cause I never used this "fies need to be served". I always save my app in a `.R` file and `add`() it to the server, that's it. it always worked, but now this stupid image doesn't want to stick into my page :-)

Comment: Good to hear. The documentation is a bit sparse. Rook is based on Ruby package Rack so it can help sometimes to see how things are done in Rack also.

Comment: I'm really sorry. Your solution does work! I just tried with another image and it shows that. The problem is that R creates a **white** image with `grid.raster`. It's very weird. It must be an issue of 3.0.0 cause I've also got 2.5.3 and it comes with the right image...